# Question which received clear and non-contradicting answers being closed as "primarily opinion-based "?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have recently asked [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/70766/is-it-appropriate-to-refer-to-god-as-it) which was closed a couple of days later. I find this strange for the following reasons:

1. **[Similar posts](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%20it%20appropriate%20) being accepted and upvoted**
2. **Agreement** - all the answers are virtually the same (no, it is not appropriate) indicating that it is something unanimously accepted, not just an opinion
3. **Some answers provide references** - this is a clear indication that it is not based on opinion only

Considering above **why was the question closed as primarily opinion based?** Of course, any piece of advice to fix the question is appreciated.

Comment: Your "similar posts" link shows either closed questions or ones with a denominational scope (often catholic, for some reason). I found only 1 question in that search list, and I voted to close it as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to this question would be to ask what groups use non-masculine pronouns, and **what is their reasoning for that**, given that the scriptures exclusively use masculine pronouns. This question scopes answers toward a particular belief or practice and how that is defended. This is like a broader version of denominational scope (e.g. catholic, mormon, etc.).

Here are a few questions along this topic:

- [Do any Christian groups refer to God as "she", "it" or "they"? (Or is it always "He"?)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36254/do-any-christian-groups-refer-to-god-as-she-it-or-they-or-is-it-always)

  This would be very similar to your question, and it's a dangerously close to a list question, which is typically not well received. It has probably been allowed, because there are very few Christian groups that use any non-masculine pronouns to refer to God. The difference between this one and how you might ask your question is that you are asking, in their words, what is the defense for using a non-masculine pronoun.
- [Why is God considered by many to be a male?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/65773/3961)

  This is the reverse of what your question would be. It is asking, for those who believe that God is male or that male pronouns should be used, what is their defense.
- [Is there any biblical justification for referring to God as Mother?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4980/3961)

  This question is asking for the biblical basis of a certain term. "Biblical basis" is a specific and narrow kind of defense that this site has developed, and it is very appropriate to ask for the biblical basis of any belief or practice of christians.

  I'll note here that this question is from 2011, so its answers are not appropriate, and don't actually answer the question according to today's site guidelines.  Appropriate answers must stick to the frame, which is, they must use the arguments of the proponents of this practice to answer the question. This makes the difference between a prescriptive and a descriptive answer.
- [How do we know to refer to the Holy Spirit as He?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6000/3961)

  This question perhaps needs an edit to be more clear, but the following is certainly on topic: "What support is there for referring to the Holy Spirit as He?"  Again, we have a question asking for the defense of a certain belief. It is asking for a descriptive answer, not what is actually true or what people suggest he should do (prescriptive answers).

With these examples, I hope I've made it clear how you can take this topic and ask a question that draws out descriptive answers instead of opinion-based prescriptive answers.

Answer (score 6):

You were lucky that only conservative answers were given, but given time other competing answers surely would have been written. If you haven't come across Christians who call God pronouns other than he/him, then your experience of broader Christianity is far from complete. By comparison, the other questions in that search which are still open are ones which are appropriately scoped.

Proper scoping (Is it acceptable according to the Catholic Church/Presbyterianism/LDS/Southern Baptists/etc) accomplishes two things: it limits the answers to only one perspective, so that the question won't turn into a perspective popularity contest; and it requires references to not only be given, but to be relevant to the perspective.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, this would make it too broad rather than primarily opinion based.